# Do I need to specify lang attribute for iframe documents?

Tags: html, screen-readers, wcag, wcag2.0

If I understand properly guide rules for lang attribute, it should suffice to declare lang for top frame html element:

https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H57.html
https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.1.2

Is it true? I just want to be sure if for example Braille readers would properly recognize language of iframe documents, if I only set lang on top window.

Answer (score 1):

Documents loaded into `iframes` are still separate documents and do not inherit anything from the document containing the `iframe` element.

They might also be loaded outside of the `iframe`.

So yes, specify the `lang` for each document, even if you intend to only load it into a frame.